# How show series points as X axis labels in asp.net chart

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, charts

I am plotting a chart where i have X axis values of the form long which is incremented but with not in specific manner for eg.
2001, 2098, 3331, 3378 .....so on.
I am trying to plot a line chart using asp.net Chart. When i set

```
         Chart1.ChartAreas["time"].AxisX.Interval = 1
```

the labels on X axis disappears, and when I set it to

```
         Chart1.ChartAreas["time"].AxisX.IntervalAutoMode = IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount
```

it rounds off to nearest value and decided its own interval.

My target is to show these x-axis point values as labels on my chart.

Another issue- 
Is there any way to use Marker as hyper link
for this i am using code

```
      for (i = 0; i < Chart1.Series["series1"].Points.Count; i++)
            {

               Chart1.Series["series1"].Points[i].Label = "xvalue string";
               Chart1.Series["series1"].Points[i].LabelAngle = -30; 
               Chart1.Series["series1"].Points[i].LabelToolTip = "xyz";
               Chart1.Series["series1"].Points[i].LabelUrl = "CustomPage.aspx";
            }
```

But this plots chart with labels and points connected with an arrow. the chart plotted is not clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do,

```
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Label = "#VALX";
Chart1.Series["Series1"].Points[i].LabelUrl = "~/CustomPage.aspx";
```

You get:
[image]

Where labels for each point are hyperlinks to your `CustomPage.aspx`(note the tooltip at the bottom).

Comment: Thanks for the response. it worked for me. Can you please suggest lablel.url if I want to pass datapoint as parameter. For eg:      ..Label.ur = "Custompage.apsx/someparameter={0}"

Comment: well i resolved it, it can be something like label.url="Customepage.aspx?someparameter=#VALX";

Comment: If my post solved your question, please remember to mark it as the accepted answer as as described here: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)